# Is there a way to change the color of the actual vertices?

Tags: vertices, customization

By default in edit mode, the vertices are black, which can be a pain if outlining a reference image when the image is black. Is there a way to change the color of the vertices, or better yet set them to invert colors?

Comment: Don't know how to set them to inverted colors, but for a simple color change see my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

To change the color of the vertices to a color of your choice, go to the top menu *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Themes* > *3D Viewport* and change the color for *Vertex*.

[image: vertex color]